# Can I call multiple tracking pixels with an image pixel?

Tags: javascript, php, pixel

Can I call mutiple tracking pixels with an image pixel?

My main tracking pixel would be -->

```
<img src="http://domain.com/pixel/123" alt="" style="height:1px;width:1px;border:0 none" />
```

However, if I do mod_rewrite, could I also call the other pixels in the phph file?

Basically, I can place only one tracking pixel, but would need to call all the pixels from below.

```
<img src="http://domain.com/pixel/123" alt="" style="height:1px;width:1px;border:0 none" />
<img src="http://domain1.com/pixel/232" alt="" style="height:1px;width:1px;border:0 none" />
<img src="http://domain2.com/pixel/745" alt="" style="height:1px;width:1px;border:0 none" />
<img src="http://domain3.com/pixel/478" alt="" style="height:1px;width:1px;border:0 none" />
<img src="http://domain4.com/pixel/894" alt="" style="height:1px;width:1px;border:0 none" />
```

Also, for the task, I can' use server to server tracking or iframe tracking. So I would need a way to load the pixels from above in one file.

Answer (score 2):

You're loading 5 different resources (tracking pixels) from 5 different domains, so you need the client to do the 5 requests: no server-side stuff will work (server will only have HTTP headers for "domain.com", and no for "domain*.com").

You may use CSS with 5 background image layers:

- external, loaded through `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..."/>`
- internal with `<style>...</style>`
- inside a `style` attribute)

Example with `style` attribute:

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://domain.com/pixel/123'), url('http://domain1.com/pixel/232'), url('http://domain2.com/pixel/745'), url('http://domain3.com/pixel/478'), url('http://domain4.com/pixel/894');">&#xnbsp;</div>
```

If CSS is not enabled, tracking won't work.
You can put the `style` attribute on an existing element.

There is no other way apart (edit in case I've forget some):

- Multiple `<img.../>` tags
- CSS `background-image: url()...;`
- Multiple `<iframe...></iframe>`
- Multiple `<link.../>` (then "tracking pixels" become "tracking CSS/external resource")
- Javascript loading (`XMLHttpRequest` or others ways to load resources)